# Input a wall of text onto windows phone 7 visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, richtextbox, textblock

I would like to know how to type in a wall of text visual studio windows phone 7.
In a way, as though we are typing on microsoft word, to design the windows application. I was thinking of adding a textblock, but it doesn't seem to have any paragraphing to it, and i couldn't find a solution to using a richtextbox to type in the details i want.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBlock` is used for displaying static pieces of text. For text input either use `RichTextBox` or a regular `TextBox`. While the latter is easier to use, the former allows for paragraphing, styling and much much more.

Note that you could use inlines in `TextBlock` to simulate paragraphs with different styling although that is not optimal.